# Как найти значение функции?

Tags: c++, функции, математика

можете помочь решить задачку?Я ещё не совсем разобрался в синтаксисе c++.
Вот Условие (, ) =1/5* + sqrt(exp(x-1)+exp(y-1)/cossqr(x+2y).
У меня получился примерно такой код:

```
//вычислить значение функции
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    float x, y;
    cout << "x = ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "y = ";
    cin >> y;
    float c = 1.0 / 5; x * y + sqrt(exp(x - 1)) + exp(y - 1) / cos(x + 2 * y);
    cout << "Результат: " << c << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Что тут не так?Напишите пожалуйста верный вариант.
[image: Функция]

Comment: почти все так - только проверьте скобки - они у вас расставлены неправильно :) и `1.0 / 5;` - тут надо умножить поставить вместо `;`

Comment: Хорошо,с умножением я исправил:)А что со скобками не так?@Zhihar

Comment: И ещё,как написать cos в квадрате(x+2y)?@Zhihar

Comment: А где у вас должна стоять закрывающая скобка для первого корня? И еще - да, вы правильно делаете, что задаете вопрос текстом... Только продублируйте формулу картинкой, а то она совершенно непонятна, где заканчивается одна функция и начинается вторая - и какая...

Comment: @Harry Картинку добавил.Номер 2 мы решаем.

Comment: @Юрий, есть функция `pow` для этих целей, но если выражение, которое надо возвести в квадрат не очень большое, то можно просто умножить его на него же `cos(...) * cos(...)`

Comment: Окей,хорошо,буду иметь ввиду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
c = cos(x+2*y);
c = x*y/5 + sqrt((exp(x-1)+exp(y-1))/(c*c));
```

Comment: Окей,спасибо)Теперь визуалка выдаёт правильный результат.